# use compass framework and compile with something else

Tags: sass, gulp, compass-sass, gulp-sass

do I have to compile with compass in order to use it framework ?
is it possible to use compass framework and compile sass with an other tool like gulp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [gulp-compass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-compass) to compile compass.

Main thing about compass vs sass is being able to use `@include x(y);` to get browser prefixes (at least from my experience). You could also use [gulp-autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer) and [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) to accomplish something similar.

I use .scss files (because I like semi-colons) but a sass builder with my gulp file:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(settings.sass.input)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass(settings.sass.options).on('error', errorLog))
            .pipe(autoprefixer(settings.sass.autoprefixer).on('error', errorLog))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(settings.maps, {
            sourceMappingURL: file => {
                return file.relative + '.map';
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(settings.sass.output))
    .resume();
});
```

I used to use compass, then it started taking 10-15 seconds to compile, and ended up switching back to just using sass (though with a .scss file type).

Comment: gulp-compass is what i needed. thanx